# How to fix "specify a valid range of job id's for WorkManager to use"

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-workmanager, jobservice

I've extended `JobService` as such:

```java
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The entire class code is highlighted in yellow.
The warning says:

> Specify a valid range of job id's for WorkManager to use.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Are you using androidx's WorkManager? If so adding [setJobSchedulerJobIdRange](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder#setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(int,%20int)) should help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning suggests, that as long as an implementation of `JobService` class is created then user should be specifying which IDs the `WorkManager` is eligible to use *"in order to not clash job codes used in the rest of your app"* (see dosc at [`setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder#setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(int,%20int))).

This should be done upon creation of `androidx.work.Configuration` instance:

```
Configuration.Builder builder = new Configuration.Builder();
builder.setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(0, 1000);
...
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't make the thing work for my setup and I had to look into the sources of lint ([`SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRangeIssueDetector`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager-lint/src/main/java/androidx/work/lint/SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRangeIssueDetector.kt)). As I can understand from the logic, as soon as there is a
method call to `setJobSchedulerJobIdRange` (see line [92](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager-lint/src/main/java/androidx/work/lint/SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRangeIssueDetector.kt#92)) - then the detector will assume that job range id has been specified by the user, but that doesn't work (at least on my machine).

Unfortunately, checking the [test class](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:work/workmanager-lint/src/test/java/androidx/work/lint/SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRangeIssueDetectorTest.kt;l=46?q=SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRangeIssueDetector) for the detector didn't convey anything either.

As for now I can claim that:

- creating a kotlin class that extends `JobService` **doesn't** result in a lint warning
- creating a java class that extends `JobService` results in a lint warning, but that doesn't get fixed even when `setJobSchedulerJobIdRange()` is performed in some other class other than the `JobService`

Interestingly, calling `setJobSchedulerJobIdRange()` in the `JobService` class fixes the warning:

[image]

Apparently, there are some issues with this detector implementation (or on my machine).

Nevertheless, if you've specified the range of IDs that WorkManager is free to use (i.e. you have called `setJobSchedulerJobIdRange()`) - then you're good to suppress this warning.

Comment: Looks like a Lint bug...

Comment: By the time you provided the answer, I had lost interest in this topic, so unfortunately, I didn’t share the 50 reward points with you.

I don't wish to check your solution now as I'm no longer interested in mobile development. However, after reading your answer, I got the impression that you answered the question well. I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

For Kotlin, you can add your Configuration.Builder() inside of init.

```
class MyJobService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    init {
        // need minimum 1000 job ids
        Configuration.Builder().setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(0, 1000).build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Implement Configuration.Provider](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration#implement-configuration-provider)
2. Specify the range of android.app.job.Job Info IDs that WorkManager can use. [setJobSchedulerJobIdRange](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder#setJobSchedulerJobIdRange(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int))
3. You can suppress the warning as follows, example:

> ```
> android {
>     lintOptions {
>        disable 'SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRange'
>     } 
> }
> ```

[more information here](https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/SpecifyJobSchedulerIdRange.md.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format the code in your answer.